# Vue.js making object.length value reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Trying to display Total records. Students.length works the first time on page load thanks to the created() method. However, calling filteredStudents(), is out of date. What is the easiest way to make this reactive?

```
<template>
        <div class="d-inline-flex flex-row p-4 col-2">
          Total record(s): {{ recordCount }}
        </div>

    <table class="table border table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="bg-secondary">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="student in filteredStudents()" :key="student._id">
                <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    import MixinCommon from '@/mixins/common.js'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                searchTerm: '',
                Students: [],
                studentcount: 0
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.Students = this.getSutdentList()
        },
        computed: {
            recordCount() {
                return this.Students.length
            }
        },
        mixins: [MixinCommon],
        methods: {
            filteredStudents() {
                return this.searchStudentList(this.searchTerm.toUpperCase(), this.Students)
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: computed prop instead of a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the implementation of the `searchStudentsList` method, but you could try using the `filteredStudents` as a computed property, or making a watch property on the `searchTerm` in order to make the search again:

**Using computed**:

```
<template>
        <div class="d-inline-flex flex-row p-4 col-2">
          Total record(s): {{ recordCount }}
        </div>

    <table class="table border table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="bg-secondary">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="student in filteredStudents" :key="student._id">
                <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    import MixinCommon from '@/mixins/common.js'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                searchTerm: '',
                Students: [],
                studentcount: 0
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.Students = this.getSutdentList()
        },
        computed: {
            recordCount() {
                return this.Students.length
            },
            filteredStudents() {
                return this.searchStudentList(this.searchTerm.toUpperCase(), this.Students)
            },
        },
        mixins: [MixinCommon],
    }
</script>
```

**Using watch property**:

```
<template>
        <div class="d-inline-flex flex-row p-4 col-2">
          Total record(s): {{ recordCount }}
        </div>

    <table class="table border table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="bg-secondary">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="student in filteredStudents" :key="student._id">
                <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    import MixinCommon from '@/mixins/common.js'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                searchTerm: '',
                Students: [],
                filteredStudents: [],
                studentcount: 0
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.Students = this.getSutdentList()
            this.filteredStudents = this.searchStudentList(this.searchTerm.toUpperCase(), this.Students)
        },
        computed: {
            recordCount() {
                return this.Students.length
            }
        },
        watch: {
          searchTerm(newValue) {
            this.filteredStudents = this.searchStudentList(newValue.toUpperCase(), this.Students)
          }
        }
        mixins: [MixinCommon],
    }
</script>
```